# Adding bash functions to the $PATH or to bash shell automatically

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Is there a way to add bash functions to the $PATH, or to the bash shell, without requiring an end-user to source them manually?

In other words, if we have a software library that exports only bash functions, we normally require the end-user to source the bash scripts with

```
. "$HOME/.the_scripts/"*.sh
```

and then using them. But is there a way to somehow get the bash functions into the shell without requiring the user to add a line of code to ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, etc?

**What am I trying to do?** I am trying to obviate the need for users to add a call to source a bash script for a library they just installed.

Comment: Depends on the OS or distro.

Comment: Not really. You can't really force a user to accept your functions without at least some acknowledgement on their part, especially in an active shell. You can insert the import into a lower level file, like /etc/bashrc, but that won't make a big conceptual difference.

Comment: This smells like XY problem BTW. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am trying to remove the need for users to add a call to source a bash script for a library they just installed.

Comment: Why not add the line to bashrc as part of your installation? Anaconda does exactly that.

Comment: I believe it's a faux pas to write to someone else's bashrc or bash_profile on their behalf

Comment: You are probably looking for a feature never copied from korn shell to bash called `FPATH`.  There are a few attempts to emulate, but they are clunky.

Comment: Perhaps with BASH_ENV. Take a look at this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428175/how-to-export-all-bash-functions-in-a-file-in-one-line/431903#431903 .You can get some ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion I got was to write a container script, to a folder, where  that folder is already in the $PATH.

Say I have a script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_func(){
   echo "this is my func, $1, $2, $3"
   export foo="my_func"
}

my_func a b c
```

I could write that script to a folder in $PATH and then execute the script, which will then call the bash function(s).

Not sure how great/universal a solution this is, but it would work for some use cases I suppose. This will **not** work if you want to export env variables to the current shell, etc, because the bash function(s) would be run in a subshell as far as I know from the command line / current script.

Answer (score 1):

If you read about the [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files), you notice that `/etc/profile` is one of the files that is processed. If you read that file, you'll see that it sources all *.sh files in /etc/profile.d

If you can have your script libraries installed in /etc/profile.d, the functions will be available for all interactive login shell sessions.

Comment: cool thanks, but I believe that writing to /etc/profile requires root privileges on most machines, I should have stipulated in the question that non-root user is preferred